# Xamarin Fails to Resolve Path to Dependent Project Correctly

Tags: msbuild, mono, xamarin, assemblies

When trying to build a solution developed in VS2010, I get the following error in one of the subprojects that depends on a DLL built by another project in the solution, though it seems to have all the project references correctly interpreted by Xamarin Studio (v5.7.0).

```
/path/to/failing/project/myproject.csproj (Build) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.12.0/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets (ResolveAssemblyReferences target) ->

  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.12.0/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference '/path/to/successful/parent/project/library/bin/ReleaseMac//mylibrary.dll' not resolved
```

After this error, there are subsequent compilation errors like:

```
The type or namespace name 'MyLibrary' could not be found.  Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

These are presumably related to the fact that the DLL that did not resolve correctly contains that namespace.

Might this also be related to [Xamarin not resolving references correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561198/xamarin-not-resolving-references-correctly)?

Comment: Yes it is definitely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561198/xamarin-not-resolving-references-correctly, as closing a reopening Xamarin Studio resolves it temporarily